# Path error when running react-native project on my macbook

Tags: javascript, react-native

It is a path error, but I never modify file.

The file exists. My project path is `'../test'.` test folder is my project `root dir.` but the err msg tell me the root is `'test/node_modules/react-native/packager';`, It is wrong.

I think the project config is wrong, but I don't know how to modify config.

[image]

Comment: it looks like index you are missing index.ios.js. Can you make sure it exists?

Comment: it is exists. my project path is '../test'. test folder is my project root dir. but the err msg tell me roots is 'test/node_modules/react-native/packager' , it is wrong. I think the project config is woring, but i dont know how to modify config.

Comment: How do you create your react native project?

Comment: use react-native-cli

Comment: could you share file structure

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have a index.ios.js file, so it can't run the thing. You would have the same issue if you ran a Android simulator and didn't have index.android.js. If your react app is in the App.js file:

```
cp App.js index.ios.js
```

in your react project folder.